# How does the Mac choose which connection to use when both Wifi and Ethernet are connected?

Tags: network, wifi, ethernet

When I'm connected to two networks with separate routers using Wifi and Ethernet, how does my Mac know what connection to use when I visit a website?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

From the Apple Support database article [regarding network connection priority](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202480):

> If you connect to the Internet or a network in several different ways
>   (using Wi-Fi or Ethernet, for example), you can change the order of
>   the network port configurations your computer tries when connecting to
>   the Internet or network.
>
> If there are multiple active network port configurations when you try
>   to connect, OS X tries the one at the top of the list first, and then
>   tries the other port configurations in descending order.

In that support article it is also described how you can change the priority order of network connections in System Preferences.

Comment: If ethernet is higher priority but disabled & Wifi is enabled & connected, what will happen when I plug in to ethernet? Will I disconnect from the network & reconnect? Or stay connected via Wifi?

Comment: → anotherdave: the Wi-Fi interface will be turned down
(equivalent of an `ifconfig en1 down`), and the Ethernet interface will be turned up (equivalent of an `ifconfig en0 up`). If this last one is based on DHCP, this will cause a DHCP request and answer (< 6 s).
If any of your interfaces have intermitent drop out, this will lead to an endless interfaces switching and DHCP requests.

Comment: This doesn't explain how a user can know **which** interface is **now** used for outgoing trafic, when several interfaces are actives and connected.

Comment: Is ther eany way to route all ssh traffic over wifi and rest over en0 (LAN)?

Comment: Just note. Since Apple engineers are stupid as, you can only use one interface at a time. And you need to order the one on top you want to use. If you try to access an IP that is not on the top most interface it simply will not work.

Comment: @JulianF.Weinert could you back this up? I do this regularly.

Comment: this is a good thread. if you are connected via Wifi only and then connect a wired( eg thunderbolt to ethernet adapter) and the thunderbolt connection has priority, how does macOS react? Does it switch existing connections to the higher priority connection? does it leave existing where they are and only new ones are on the new connection? this is the real question.

Answer (score 79):

It's in your **Network Preferences**. Here's screen shots from 10.7.3.

Access the settings from the gear at the bottom of the network type sidebar.

[image]

Choose "Set Service Order..." to drag them into the preferred order.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't explain how a user can know **which** interface is **now** used for outgoing trafic, when several interfaces are actives and connected. <br>With such a configuration the **Wi-Fi** icon in the menu bar may be full black when in fact all your network activity is going through the **Ethernet**! Such a configuration may create a network loop no user will ever be able to see and debug.

Comment: @danielAzuelos Sure, but that's not the question here. It's about how the Mac chooses, which is a priority based system. If the one on top is working, you're connected. In the main network panel, you can see what interfaces are connected and whether or not it's a successful connection. Cross-ref that with your priority list and you *should* have your answer.

Comment: @plainclothes what if you connect / disconnect network interfaces? how does macOS behave? say I'm on wifi and then connect ethernet so now I have both. What happens with existing and now connections? what if I do the opposite? how does priority play into all of  this?

Answer (score 20):

I recommand you to never use a configuration where you *may* have at the same
time different interfaces up on the same machine. You won't have any easy knowledge and control of this dual connectivity.

This may lead to huge difficulties to analyse even the simplest network trouble.

This may also cause loops within company or personnal networks very hard to diagnose. For example, have a look at the following command:

```
sysctl -a | grep forwarding
```

which will show you if `IPv4` or `IPv6` is going *through* your Mac from one
interface through the other without your knowledge or control.

As much as possible define *locations* with the interface you know you want to
connect to and switch on the right one at will:

```
Apple menu > Location > Home / AirPort
                      > Office / Ethernet
                      > outside / AirPort [unsecure]
                      > …
```

---

When 2 (or more) interfaces (for example `Ethernet` **and** `Wi-Fi`) are flagged green (Connected) within:

```
Apple menu > System Preferences… > Network
```

one way to know which one you are taking to reach the outside is the following line command (within a `Terminal` or `xterm` window):

```
route get default | grep interface
```

Comment: All the answers explain it on a different level. This one is the best because you can see the changes the computer is making when setting the order through the UI like in the screenshots from @plainclothes

Answer (score 7):

The Service Order doesn't work.  If you test it, you will find that Mac OS prioritizes Wifi over Ethernet, even if Ethernet is set higher in the Service Order.

One way to test it is to measure your bandwidth (e.g., https://www.fast.com) in the following scenarios:

1. Connected to Wifi, with Ethernet unplugged
2. Connected to Ethernet, with Wifi turned off
3. Connected to Wifi and Ethernet

You will find that the speed from #2 is faster than #1 and #3.  You will also find that #1 and #3 are the same speed.

The only solution is to disable WiFi when you connect via Ethernet and turn on Wifi when you disconnect Ethernet.

This script does that automatically!

https://gist.github.com/albertbori/1798d88a93175b9da00b

If you have any issues, search the comments for the error message you encounter.  For example, I got the `Path had bad ownership/permissions` error, but the solution is posted in the comments.

Comment: 1. wlan connected -> all data through wlan
2. wlan connected + lan connected -> all new data through lan, established connections stay an wlan.

Comment: My test also did not find what was hypothesized (on macOS Sonoma 14.0).

Internet speed was fastest when Ethernet was plugged in, regardless of Wifi connection — 5 to 7 times faster than when only WiFi was connected.

If you want to see the speedtest results: https://imgur.com/a/V9y94Ir

Answer (score -1):

While this is true for some applications, what I experienced when I had connected my iMac to two ISP's - one wifi and another through LAN - applications like uTorrent and Games could apparently use both networks simultaneously. I got more download speed than individual connections and in case of multiplayer games, I could connect to servers with less lag and latency.

Comment: BitTorrent was built for multiple connections. But most everything else only uses one connection including games. Want proof? Watch your packets and which interfaces they use.

Answer (score -1):

When my M1 iMac arrives, I will be connecting to my old 2013 27" iMac which I'm keeping until a 32-bit program's conversion to 64-bit is beta.  I could use Wi-Fi or an ethernet cable (My old Mac has Thunderbolt-1).   And I plan on doing some data transferring with my wife's newer iMac with a Thunderbolt-3 cable, carrying my Mac into her Mac's room.

I figure the Thunderbolt-3 is fastest, and Wi-Fi's slowest.

I'm guessing that I should turn off Wi-Fi while I'm doing the transferring, and that's all I will need to do.   Is that correct?

Comment: Hi, you've mistakenly pressed the `Post Your Answer` button, while you have a new question. Please [ask a new question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), describing what issue you have and what you've looked into so far.